# Ngcordova fileupload camera ios error code 1

Tags: ios, ngcordova

I have a problem with ios and ngcordova fileupload. Somehow i get an error code 1 in ios but i dont know why.

This is where i retrieve the image from camera

```
$scope.getPictureFromCamera = function(){
    var options = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        allowEdit: false,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 1000,
        targetHeight: 1000,
        correctOrientation: true,
        popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageURI){
        $scope.displayURL = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageURI;
        $scope.pictureURL = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageURI;
    },
    function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

This is where i upload the image to my server

```
createPostWithPicture: function(post, pictureURI){

        var url = domain+'/api/v1/statuses/create';
        var filePath = pictureURI;
        var options = {
            "fileKey": "sphoto",
            "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
            "params": post
        }

        return $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(url, filePath, options);
    },
```

In Android everything is working fine. In IOS i get an error with the following message:

```
FileTransferError { code = 1; source = data:image/jpeg;base64,....
```

I really cant find any solution to this. Help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like IOS wants Camera.DestinationType to be FILE_URL. So i changed my function to

```
$scope.getPictureFromCamera = function(){
    var options = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: false,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 1000,
      targetHeight: 1000,
      correctOrientation: true,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    };
    if(device.platform == "Android"){
        options.destinationType = Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL;
    }

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageURI){
        if(device.platform == "Android"){
            $scope.displayURL = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageURI;
            $scope.pictureURL = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageURI;
        } else if(device.platform == "iOS"){
            $scope.displayURL = imageURI;
            $scope.pictureURL = imageURI;
        }
    },
    function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```